# Is there any API in softlayer to resize a virtual guest. I am unable to find any in the documentation in softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to resize a virtual guest in softlayer. The CLI command is 
ibmcloud sl vs upgrade 75673473 -c 8 -m 8192 --network 1000

I am searching for an equivalent rest API call, where I can possibly pass a flavor rather than specifying the memory and cpu separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following slcli command:

```
slcli virtual upgrade --flavor B1_2X8X25 11111
```

Replace the 11111 for your virtual server id and the "B1_2X8X25" data for the flavor keyName you want to upgrade.

To retrieve the flavors keyNames available you can use the below slcli command:

```
slcli call-api Product_Package getActivePresets --id=835
```

Reference:

https://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/